# Is there any Function module to update the custom fields of VBRK table?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have a requirement to update the custom fields - zzpdf and zzpdfdt of VBRK table. When executing program it should update zzpdf with X (Active) and zzpdfdt with the current date.
So is there any Function module I can use here so the fields are updated like this?

Comment: Why do you need a function module to update a custom column, why don't you use SQL?

Comment: Same question asked here, with existing answers: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13556706/function-module-to-update-custom-fields-of-vbrk-ta.html